# What happens if you send an instance of an ES6 class via REST API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, es6-class

```
class Data {

  #some_private_var

  constructor(private_val, regular_val) {
    this.regular_var = regular_val
    this.#some_private_var = private_val
  }
}
```

For example, if I use Axios to make an API request with an instance of the above class as the body of the request, what gets send over to the server?

Will `#some_private_var` get sent over?

What if a getter method is defined like so:

```
  get some_private_var() {
    return this.#some_private_var
  }
```

Comment: Axios won't be able to access `.#some_private_var`, it's private!

Comment: So you are saying that only `regular_var` will be sent over?

Comment: Instead of asking here, why not just test it and see what gets sent?

Comment: Best way to know whether something works or not.... the best policy (in most cases) is to try yourself.

Comment: According to the documentation, "*By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to `JSON`.*" So unless you set a specific content-type, [`JSON.stringify` happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848044/private-fields-in-javascript-dont-show-up-in-json-stringify).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios by default serialises JavaScript objects via [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

You can easily see what the result of that would be. The behaviour of which is [defined here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description)...

> All the other `Object` instances [...] will have only their **enumerable properties** serialized.

```js
class Data {

  #some_private_var

  constructor(private_val, regular_val) {
    this.regular_var = regular_val;
    this.#some_private_var = private_val;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(new Data("private", "regular")));
```

Private properties and methods are not *enumerable properties*.

If you want to expose members that would otherwise be hidden, create a [`toJSON()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior)

> If an object being stringified has a property named `toJSON` whose value is a function, then the `toJSON()` method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the `toJSON()` method when called will be serialized

```js
class Data {

  #some_private_var

  constructor(private_val, regular_val) {
    this.regular_var = regular_val;
    this.#some_private_var = private_val;
  }
  
  toJSON() {
    return {
      ...this,
      some_private_var: this.#some_private_var
    };
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(new Data("private", "regular")));
```